# jQuery column filters

Tags: jquery

I have an application which presents a list of clients in a table. There are 485 rows in this table. In the `thead` there is a textbox which allows the user to filter on the value entered in the column in which the textbox appears. It seems that whenever the user enters a letter in one of these fields it takes so long that Firefox displays the prompt about the script not responding.

Before anyone suggests it, paging is not an option here - the idea is that it displays the full client list and then the user filters on a certain value in a certain column.

Currently I am using the following method to filter each column:

```
$inputs.keyup(function() {
    $header = $(this).closest("th").attr("data-header-name");
    $table = $(this).closest("table").find("tbody");
    $rows = $table.find("tr");
    $rows.not(":visible").show(0);
    $input = $(this);
    if(!($.trim($input.val())) == "") {
         $rows.filter(function(i) {
             return ($(this).find("td").filter(function() {
                 return ($(this).attr("headers") == $header)
             }).html().toLowerCase().indexOf($input.val().toLowerCase()) == -1);
         }).hide(0);
    }
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to improve this so that it is a lot faster? Thanks in advance.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4ngs/7/)

Regards,
Richard

Comment: have you checked jquery datatables http://datatables.net/ ?

Comment: Hi Rodolfo, now that this has been suggested I may look into this (particularly as this is needed very soon). I have to admit I knew about this kind of plugin but didn't want to consider it as an option as I like learning about these things myself and improving my knowledge.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.picnet.com.au/picnet-table-filter.html. Even if you don't want to use that as is, you can look at the code to see how it is done in an optimal way. ~500 rows don't seem too many although without looking at the sample HTML it is hard to say that. Can you create a fiddle for that?

Comment: Hi amit_g, unfortunately I cannot provide an example for confidentiality reasons (providing an example will tell you most of our clients). It is a table containing 5 columns and 500 rows. The DB is joined to a DB on another server using `linked servers` but I doubt this makes a difference as the filtering is being done by jQuery, not SQL. By the time the user types anything the full client list is already loaded. 5 columns and 500 rows hardly seems like much - 2500 values to look through at the most.

Comment: You don't have to post the real data just the real markup :)

Comment: Ok I've added a JS Fiddle. It seems that the loop for adding all the rows (which I am using because jsFiddle chokes when I paste a table containing 500 rows) is very quick indeed. All of the initial set up is very quick. But type a number into the first column and it goes a little wobbly and sometimes stops responding. I can't see any way to speed this up. To my knowledge we only have 1 server with that many clients on it so it should be ok for the rest.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy so my answer didn't work?  Your issue is the inefficient use of jQuery during the keyup event.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it yet. I have, using the console, narrowed it down to the td selector - that selector is rather 'tdious' lol. I may have come up with an alternate solution. Basically all clients are first loaded into JS objects and then the data is copied from them into the table. If I were to give each row a unique ID (using the client ID) then I can just loop through the clients, check the relevant attribute and hide / show the row with that client ID. I'll try that first as it should be relatively simple to do and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Well that certainly works a lot faster - it takes about 5 seconds in Chrome and 7-10 seconds in FF now. One thing I just thought of - this is an internal app for which I am using Windows Auth. This means that within the directory I could put 'parts' - pages which are loaded using the jQuery load method. All I'd have to do is pass the type of object to display (client, agency, user etc.), columns and filters in the URL and use SQL to decide what to return. It would also be a lot easier for others to support then as most other devs don't really know jQuery that well.

Comment: Yep server side would likely be faster for internal app due to low latency.  I also agree with @Rodolfo, datatables.net is an amazing tool that I use quite often.  But if you are wanting to learn JS optimizations for lookups, you'll want to first reduce your jQuery calls during the search, second pre-generate some type of lookup table and third handle fast typers if you are using instant search (don't want them searching for "cl", "cli", "clie", etc all at once).  Good luck

Comment: You have a very specific html/js setup with additional attributes, etc.  My answer is just a generic drop-in anyone could use on a standard HTML table to do fast column-based filtering.  (I actually wrote it yesterday because I needed to write a new client side lookup myself next week anyway for data views I'm not using jQuery datatables on).

Comment: I've actually got several big projects on the go which I am currently merging into one location, so I have an asp Class called Client, Agency etc and I just call myClient.writeList() and myClient.writeItem etc. The classes themselves do all the checking for permissions, id parameters etc. Its a nightmare right now as they were all written in different ways. I think using 'parts' is the way forward, and I have made the keyup event only load the results when the user hits enter. That way they can enter an entire clients name, for example, and then search for them.

Answer (score 1):

Just threw this together and it is not mindful of multiple filters at once but should give you some ideas on how to optimize.  It only uses a little jQuery and you could pretty easily replace that with vanilla JS if you wanted.

Note that I added a 500 ms delay for each keystroke to prevent overrun, this could be tweaked or probably written better but that has worked for me in the past.  Also, you gain performance by pre-building your lookup table and not calling jQuery for anything during your search operations.

```
var timeout = 0,
    columns = {};

function doFilter(that) {
    var column = columns[that.column],
        filter = that.value.toUpperCase(),
        i = column.length - 1;

    // look for our value hide row if not found
    while (i > -1) {
        var display = 'none'
        if (column[i].text.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            display = '';
        }

        column[i].el.parentNode.style.display = display;
        i--;
    }
}


/* shouldn't have to change this stuff */

$('input').each(function () {

    //Setup our columns
    var index = $(this).parent().prevAll().length + 1;

    this.column = index;
    columns[index] = [];

    // attach some data to each column
    $('td:nth-child(' + index + ')').each(function () {
        columns[index].push({
            text: this.innerHTML.toUpperCase(),
            el: this
        });
    });

}).on('keyup', function () {
    //bind our event with a 500 ms delay
    var that = this;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        doFilter(that);
    }, 500);
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jeff_mccoy/HDpr7/8/embedded/result/

The table data is from datatables.net (just the html).  Hope that helps.