# jQuery function to filter multiple column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a jQuery function to apply filters to multiple columns.
Example:

### html

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Address</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>    
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control search" onkeyup="filterTable('#myTable', $(this).val().toLowerCase(), 0);"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control search" onkeyup="filterTable('#myTable', $(this).val().toLowerCase(), 1);"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control search" onkeyup="filterTable('#myTable', $(this).val().toLowerCase(), 2);"></td>
        </tr>

        <?php while ($row = $res->fetchArray()) { ?>
        <tr>    
            <td><?php echo "{$row["address"]}"?></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row["name"]}"?></td>
            <td><?php echo "{$row["description"]}"?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### js

```
function filterTable(table, text, col) {
    $(table + " > tbody > tr").not(':first').find("td").eq(col).filter(function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1)
    });
}
```

When the `keyup` event is fired a call the `filterTable` function passing the id of the table to be filtered, the text inserted by the user and the index of the column.

**The goal is to hide the rows whose target column doesn't contain the text. I skip the first row because it contains the filter input textboxes.
I also want to let the user to enter multiple filters on different columns.**

Even typing something in only one input textbox the behavior is not correct: when I type something that doesn't match *all* the rows hide.

I searched for similar questions (i.e. [jQuery column filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163752/jquery-column-filters)) but the answers don't seem to work - when applying another filter the previous one is removed.

### UPDATE

This is the actual html code generated:

```
<table id="tableParameters" class="table table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Address</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>    
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control search" onkeyup="filterTable('#tableParameters', $(this).val().toLowerCase(), 0);"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control search" onkeyup="filterTable('#tableParameters', $(this).val().toLowerCase(), 1);"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control search" onkeyup="filterTable('#tableParameters', $(this).val().toLowerCase(), 2);"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>    
            <td>1000</td>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Date of the event</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>1001</td>
            <td>Time</td>
            <td>Time of the event</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>1002</td>
            <td>Code</td>
            <td>Requested code</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your issue seems to be front-end related. If so, please post generated HTML.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir because I load that PHP into a div at run-time, Chrome doesn't show me the actual source in the dev panel, nor using the "show source" menu item. How could I retrieve it?

Comment: Why the downvote? I showed my actual code and I gave evidence of searches.I don't understand why most of my questions are downvoted without any explanation. I cannot improve them in this way.

Comment: @Mark you can copy from the "Inspect Element" tools.

Comment: @user7290573 thanks. Question updated. Anyway the code seems exactly the same (luckily!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing it right, the `filterTable` function must be like this:

```
function filterTable(table) {
    var filterColumn1Value = $(table + " > tbody > tr:first-child").find('td').eq(0).find('input').first().val().toLowerCase();
    var filterColumn2Value = $(table + " > tbody > tr:first-child").find('td').eq(1).find('input').first().val().toLowerCase();
    var filterColumn3Value = $(table + " > tbody > tr:first-child").find('td').eq(2).find('input').first().val().toLowerCase();
    $(table + " > tbody > tr").not(':first').filter(function() {
        var column1Value = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text().toLowerCase();
        var column2Value = $(this).find("td").eq(1).text().toLowerCase();
        var column3Value = $(this).find("td").eq(2).text().toLowerCase();
        $(this).toggle(column1Value.indexOf(filterColumn1Value) > -1 &&
                column2Value.indexOf(filterColumn2Value) > -1 &&
                column3Value.indexOf(filterColumn3Value) > -1)
    });
}
```

And the calling of the function should be just:

```
filterTable('#tableParameters');
```

Comment: It works. I didn't realize I have to handle all the criteria at one time.